# Condition to make group action primitive

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G \le S_n$ and $H \le G$ be subgroup. Let $G$ acts on cosets of $H$ in $G$ and it forms a block system ($\forall \sigma \in G, S^{\sigma} = S $), where $S = \{Hg_1, ...,Hg_k\}$.

**Question :** What is the condition on $H$ such that action $\phi: G \times S \mapsto S$ is primitive (no nontrivial blocks)?

Comment: An equivalent condition for the action to be primitive is that $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Incidentally the fact that $G \le S_n$ does not seem relevant.

Comment: @ Derek Holt Reference request. in which book I will find it